# Zeros of the series $\phi(s, a) = \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-an}(n + 1)^{-s}$

Tags: zeta-functions

I have been recently interested in the series $\phi(s, a)$ of the title.

There, a is defined to be any positive real number and s is a complex variable.

The main reason for my curiosity is that the distribution of the zeros of the function
\begin{equation}
f(s) := \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{(n + ia)^{1 - s}}
\end{equation}
seems to be related to that of $\phi(s, a)$.

Now, if the number $a$ is very large, then it is easy to see that
for any s with Re s > 0,
\begin{equation}
\phi(s, a) = \sum_{n \geq 0} e^{-an}(n + 1)^{-s}
= 1 + \text{error},
\end{equation}
with $|error|\leq e^{-a}/(1 - e^{-a})$, thereby $\phi(s, a) \not = 0$
for $a$ very large.

My question is, is there any known method to analyze $\phi(s, a)$ for
small a ?

I would rather conjecture that $\phi(s, a) \not = 0$ for any $a > 0$.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: Mathematica gives $\phi(s,a)=e^{a}\ Li_{s}(e^{-a})$ with $Li_{s}$ the so called polylogarithm. There exists quite some literature on this function on the net, a starter could be http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are asking, but the entire function $f(s)=\phi(a,s)$ certainly has infinitely many zeros for any $a>0$. This follows from the [Hadamard product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function): $f$ is of order $1$ (that is, $|f(z)|\lesssim \exp (|z|^{1+\epsilon})$ for every $\epsilon>0$), but on the other hand, $|f(-R)|\gtrsim \exp (cR\log R)$, so $f$ is not a polynomial times an exponential function, and thus the product part in Hadamard's formula must have infinitely many factors.

(By the same argument, $f$ takes any value infinitely many times.)

Comment: I forgot to include the restriction "Re s > 0" in my conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

By Johannes Trost's comment, you are asking for zeros of the polylogarithm. This is a well-studied subject, see, for example, the [nice paper by Garungskis and Grigutis](http://www.mif.vu.lt/~garunkstis/preprintai/ZerosLerchTransc.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the paper. My conjecture is quite wrong, then.